# setIconImage intellij Project javax.swing

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, icons

i'm heaving a problem in setting the icon for my swing project in intellij.

I tried this

```
iconpath = execPath + File.separator +  "images" + File.separator + "icon.png";

this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(iconpath)).getImage());
```

but got

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at cgui.FormApp.<init>(FormApp.java:52)
    at controller.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:39)
Exception in thread "main"
```

and

```
iconpath = execPath + File.separator +  "images" + File.separator + "icon.png";
InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream(iconpath);

Image image = null;
try {
      image = ImageIO.read(resource);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(image).getImage());
```

and got

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
    at cgui.FormApp.<init>(FormApp.java:58)
    at controller.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:39)
Exception in thread "main"
```

I have my project structured like. Do you guys have any idea to how make this work?

[image: project folders structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the image path **relative** to Main.java.

You should get the image from the absolute path with **getClassLoader()**.

```
this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/icon.png")).getImage());
```

Comment: got

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
 at cgui.FormApp.<init>(FormApp.java:51)
 at controller.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:39)
Exception in thread "main"

Comment: and move the images folder into java folder. images/icon.png should be in target/classes

Comment: my icon file was broken. I tried with other from the internet and worked fine. Thank you so much.